# Using Multi Shader with a tracer

Tags: cinema4d

In Cinema 4D R16 and I have an animated Tube objects used together with a tracer to draw circles with Sweep nurbs.

This is my setup:

[image]

The material is a Multi Shader with two different colors, this setup works fine when the sweep is an cloner instead. Is there a way of achieving multi materials?

The animation:
[image]